# Add an Vertex Attribute to NetworkD3 object

Tags: r, text, analysis, networkd3

Greeting folks,

I have been struggling with adding a colour group to a [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) object in [r](/questions/tagged/r) for the purpose of a network visual. The code to render the visual is stable but I currently have the grouping variable set to `1`. The tricky bit is that I have a separate table for which I am using to evaluate a colour group.

I tried to add it as a vector by first generating a list.

```
V(network)$color <- group[V(network)$name]
```

I have also tried a custom function called `makeVertexAtt` as well as using `set_vertex_attr` and `vertex_attr-set` from [igraph](/questions/tagged/igraph) but to no avail. The issue I get in doing a simple join within a network object is `cannot coerce class ‘"igraph.vs"’ to a data.frame`. Fair enough, but if I create the vector and add it in I get  `Not a graph object` errors.

Let's say for example (since this is not a graph object) I have this vector of names:

```
V(Graph)$names<-c("knife","kitchen","toilet","shower","toothbrush", "shed")
```

I then have a separate data set that has two columns, the word and the category.

```
Word<-c("knife","kitchen","toilet","shower","toothbrush")
Category <-c("Kitchen","Kitchen","bathroom","bathroom","bathroom")
```

I would ideally want a V(graph)$color attribute that has a matching vector

```
V(graph)$color<-c("Kitchen","Kitchen","bathroom","bathroom","bathroom","N/A")
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an easy way to merge group information from one data frame to your nodes data frame

```
names <- c("knife", "kitchen", "toilet", "shower", "toothbrush", "shed")
nodes <- data.frame(names, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Word <- c("knife", "kitchen", "toilet", "shower", "toothbrush")
Category <- c("Kitchen", "Kitchen", "bathroom", "bathroom", "bathroom")
group <- data.frame(Word, Category, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nodes$group <- group$Category[match(nodes$names, group$Word)]

nodes
#       names    group
# 1      knife  Kitchen
# 2    kitchen  Kitchen
# 3     toilet bathroom
# 4     shower bathroom
# 5 toothbrush bathroom
# 6       shed     <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution! Works perfectly. I need to stop over thinking these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Greeting folks, I think I solved my problem. A networkD3 object is a lists of lists. Perfectly fine with that concept in Python, but in R to access the level I wasn't using two `$` to get into a lists of lists.

So instead of applying a group variable to `network.D3$nodes`. I need to add new vertices to `network.D3$nodes$group`. So to solve my problem I created a merging variable in the call at the same time,

```
group<- as.dataframe (Word,Category)

list<-merge (x=network.D3$nodes, y=group, x.by="names", y.by="Word",all.x=TRUE)

network.D3$nodes$group<-list$Category

forceNetwork(Links = network.D3$links, 
             Nodes = network.D3$nodes, 
             Source = 'source', 
             Target = 'target',
             NodeID = 'name',
             Group = 'group',
             opacity = 0.9,
             Value = 'Width',
             fontSize = 12,
             zoom = TRUE, 
             opacityNoHover = 1)
```

#### Update

I found a flaw in my plan. For some reason creating the vector as a separate evaluation and then adding it back in doesn't work because the order of the networkD3 object changes? It is bizarre behaviour. (unfortunate I cannot share the real world example because of data protection.)

So I have tried to make the evaluation within the creation of the attribute using the following code:

```
network.D3$nodes$group<- list(merge(x=network.D3$nodes,y=Lexicon, by="name", all.x = TRUE))
```

But this adds the vertex in as a data frame which then cannot be placed in a `forcenetwork`. Trying it in `plyr` didn't provide any better result.

```
network.D3$nodes$group<- Lexicon %>% join(network.D3$nodes,Lexicon,by="name",type = "left")) %>% select(list(Category_1))

>Error in match.arg(match, c("first", "all")) : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

How can I add a vector after a matching evaluation in which the result is kept as a vector that can be assigned to a networkD3 lists of lists object?